# What Data Type is an Excel Cell Reference (VBA)?

Tags: excel, named-ranges, addressing, vba

What data type is an Excel cell reference?  I have constructed strings representing cell references (e.g. "G12", "AW12", etc.), and want to use them to create named ranges;

```
Dim UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference As String
UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference = "G12"
Dim LowerRightHandCornerOfRangeCellReference As String    
LowerRightHandCornerOfRangeCellReference = "AW12"
NamedSheet.Names.Add _
            name:=RangeName, _
            RefersTo:="=Sheet!UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference:LowerRightHandCornerOfRangeCellReference"
```

but, they are not interpreted as cell references, rather the names of the respective strings, and the named range thus not created.  Any ideas? Please share. Thanks!

**Update:**

Thank you @MattCremeens for your help.

Consider if it *had* to be done this way;

```
Dim myCell1 As String
myCell1 = "G12"
Dim myCell2 As String
myCell2 = "AW12"
NamedSheet.Names.Add _
            name:=RangeName, _
            RefersTo:="=Sheet!myCell1:myCell2"
```

such would not work because the quotations in the 'RefersTo' parameter do not allow the string variables 'myCell(1/2)' to be read.  Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: It is a range. So you can use `Dim myCell as Range`.

Comment: Hi @MattCremeens ---Do you mean the strings can be reassigned as ranges? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can add a string that represents a cell reference as a parameter to `Range(...)`. See my answer below.

Comment: @PBG Hi PBG! Rather than adding an edit to thank Matt for his help, you can click the check mark under his answer to mark this question as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are meaning to do is

```
Dim UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference As Range    
Set UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference = Range("G12")
```

Must use the `Set` keyword when assigning ranges to variables.

If you want to store your string like

```
myCell = "G12"
```

then just change the 2nd line above to

```
Set UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference = Range(myCell)
```

Now if you had a cell that was a named range (maybe that is what you mean by a cell reference being a string??), you could do this instead

```
Set UpperLeftHandCornerOfRangeCellReference = Worksheets("Sheet1").Names("MyRangeName").RefersToRange
```

Comment: If "G12" itself is a string, would this still work?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. "G12" is indeed a string itself.

Comment: If instead of "G12", I pass a string variable equal to "G12" to a range (i.e. Range(CellReferenceAsString)).

Comment: Like `myCell = "G12"` and then `Range(myCell)`? Yes, you could do that.

Comment: Thank you. @MattCremeens

Comment: Matt ---I actually think we have misunderstood each other.  I am trying to make a named range, specifying the 'RefersTo' parameter as a cell reference that is stored in a string variable.

Comment: Then just do `Range("G12").Name = "MyRange"`

Comment: Or if `myCell = "G12"` then just do `Range(myCell).Name = "MyRange"`.

Comment: Thanks, Matt...If you look above at my original post, though, I am trying to use the Names.Add method by substituting something like 'myCell' as a cell reference parameter (the method calls for), (see 'RefersTo:=...', specifically).

Comment: You can add a name like I demonstrated in my comment. Try it.

Comment: `Range(myCell1, myCell2).Name = "MyRange"`

Comment: Not sure what your comment means, but you could name a section of cells similarly to `Range(cells(1,1), cells(5,5)).Name = "MyRange"`.

Comment: That last comment would assign all cells in the range from A1 to E5 to the name "MyRange".

Comment: If you want to name a range that spans cells between `G12` and `AW12` (per your question), then you can just do `Range(myCell1, myCell2).Name = "MyRange"`

Comment: I understand, Matt, and thank you for your help.  I was just curious if specifically there is any way to structure the 'RefersTo' parameter such that the cell references it calls for could be substituted as string variables representing those cell references.

Comment: What I showed you and what you were trying to do with the `RefersTo` way accomplish the exact same thing. The way I showed you is more succinct and I showed you how to use variables that store strings that refer to cell ranges.

Comment: If you absolutely must use that notation, try `Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="MyRange3", RefersTo:=Range(myCell1, myCell2)`.

Comment: Matt, I understand that, and so selected your answer.  I appreciate the notation help, just above, too.  Thanks.